# C program to increment each element of an array passed

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

C novice here.
I am trying to write a program containing function that takes in an array pointer, and each element of the array passed in the main function is incremented by 1. This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void array_incr(int8_t *, uint8_t);

int main (void){
    int8_t *arr[] = {0xAB, 0xCB, 0xC4, 0x84};
    array_incr(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
}

void array_incr(int8_t *arr, uint8_t len){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        arr[i]++;

}
```

This is compiling with a lot of warnings and errors. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong, while maintaining the same format of implementation?

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."*

Comment: One pile of warnings is because `int8_t *arr[]` is an array of pointers, not an array of (small) integers.  Drop the `*`.  The variable `min_ptr` is unused and should be removed.  You should probably not use both `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` and 4 for the size of the array; the expression is better than number.

Comment: Why do you compute the size of the array to call `array_mod`, but hard-code it to print it?

Comment: The errors and warnings are *telling you* what's going wrong. Try reading them! (Also, when developing new code, always compile with all warnings enabled — add `-Wall -pedantic` to the command line.)

Comment: And `0xC4` exceds the range of `int8_t` (typicaly -128 ... 127)

Comment: @KeineLust: "**typicaly** 0 ... 127"?? - **exactly** -128..127 and nothing else!

Comment: @KeineLust: Still incorrect after the edit!

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I was thinking in `unsigned char`, `uint8_t` is _always_ in the range -128 ... 127, thank you

Comment: @KeineLust: Before we get the discussion warning: You might want to read about the valid ranges for the standard integer types as well as the extended integer types. Your asumption for `uinsigned char` is wrong, too. Just in case you have "Lust".

Comment: @Olaf, are you sure? if I remember well, in one's complement encoding the range of `signed char` was -127 ... 127 (there were + 0 and -0 in different values) , anyway you are right, `int8_t` must be encoded as a two's complement signed integer, the range is always -128 ... 127

Comment: @KeineLust: You wrote about **`unsigned`** `char`! And please read the standard about fixed width types.

Comment: @Olaf, ooops, I am totally dyslexic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems indeed:

- Incorrect type in declaration `int8_t *arr[] = {0xAB, 0xCB, 0xC4, 0x84};`: you should remove the `*` as `arr` is an array of numbers, not an array of pointers.  Furthermore, the values are larger than 127 which is the maximum value for type `int8_t`, you should use `uint8_t` or a larger type.
- Missing `)` at the end of `array_incr(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`
- There is no `\n` in the `printf("%d", arr[i]);` output statement.  The values will come out in a single sequence of digits (and negative signs, since the values are actually negative for type `int8_t`).

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void array_incr(uint8_t *, uint8_t);

int main(void) {
    uint8_t arr[] = { 0xAB, 0xCB, 0xC4, 0x84 };
    array_incr(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}

void array_incr(uint8_t *arr, uint8_t len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        arr[i]++;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, it would be best to include said list of warnings and errors, but with such a small program it's mostly alright.

Into the matter, you declared your array wrong ; it should be `int8_t arr[]` (you included an extra *). You want an array of integers, not a pointer to an array of integers nor an array of pointers to integers (you can't initialise the former like that anyway).

`sizeof` doesn't work like you think it does. It returns the number of bytes taken up by the variable or type in memory. For example, on most modern system `sizeof(int)` returns 4, as would something like `int a = 1; sizeof(a)`, and just like `sizeof(arr)` in your case. `arr` is not an array, it's a pointer to an array, so it's technically an int (thus 4 bytes). You would have to create an additional variable and manually hold the array's size if it were to change.

EDIT : tried it, seems to work. I remember that it doesn't but apparently it does ...

Comment: "on most modern system sizeof(int) returns 4" - wrong and dangerous to state to an obvious beginner. There are many modern 16 bit systems and some systems with e.g. 16 or 32 bits/byte. A pointer is **not** an `int`! It is not even an _integer_. Not sure what you mean with that extra variable. The `sizeof`? expression is the best part of that code.

Comment: Right, I should change that. Also, it seems I'm double wrong since I tested and `sizeof(arr)` does yield the correct result. Don't know where I've got that from, I'm sorry ...